# How are concubines different than wives?

Tags: genesis, history, torah, marriage

In the Hebrew Bible, a marriage ceremony is never actually described.

Priests and their attendants (Kohanim and Levites) are responsible for work in the sanctuary, such as sacrifices and offerings, so although they're the people "consecrated to God" and act as intermediaries between the people and God, they don't have any part in helping a man and woman form a permanent union as "one flesh" and become husband and wife.

In Genesis, a union between man and woman is described as just a commitment that two people make to live together, help each other, "be fruitful and multiply." Isaac brought Rebecca "into his tent," and she became his wife, so in their case, marriage is initiated between a couple when they engage in sex. Afterwards, they are understood as being bound to each other, and thus living in a marriage. This is understandable, since biblical times had a very different view of sex than what we see in modern society.

This is why I ask about the difference between what a wife is and what a concubine is in biblical times. Since a marriage ceremony is never described in the Bible, what qualities would make a concubine different than a wife?

Those are two different labels, so is it just suggesting a social status difference? A handmaid, even if she took up permanent residence with one man, would never be a "wife", only a "concubine"?

Bilhah and Zilphah are described as Jacob's "concubines", and Rachel and Leah are described as "wives", although the children from all four women are equal since they all become the twelve tribes. So why not call Rachel and Leah's handmaids wives?

Comment: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12148-pilegesh although compare to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concubine#In_the_Bible. You'll have to read all the references within for a better understanding.

Comment: Check out http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16558/is-there-any-account-of-a-religious-marriage-ceremony-in-the-scripture.  The answer includes the three Cs of marriage in the Old Testament; viz., contract, consummation, and celebration.  I imagine only true "brides" or "wives" observed all three Cs of a formal marriage.  Marriages in the OT were sometimes the means of establishing political and military alliances, and a woman involved in the transaction may have been one of a harem of many women.  As concubines, they were not necessarily wedded and bedded by the king.

Answer (score 6):

The bride (or her parents) paid the dowry. If there was a divorce the bride got her money back. Concubines got nothing after a 'divorce' as no dowry was paid. A wife paid to get married, a  concubine did not. A contract was drawn up in the case of the wife but not the concubine. This answer is based on deduction from what scriptural refereces there are and practices of other peoples of the Middle East. We still see something like this in the procurement of prostitutes that become a 'wife' (concubine) for one night and that is divorced with no paperwork the next morning.

Answer (score 5):

Basically your right it was about status but although the Bible does not describe the ceremony of marriage with a wife there are several bread crumbs that when collected together give us a good idea of the envelope of that ceremony and custom that did take place which would have established the status of a wife above a concubine.

There must have been some kind of *betrothal* for in  Joel 1:8 the allusion to it is made by the statement to 'Mourn like a virgin in sackcloth grieving for the *betrothed* of her youth'.  There was some kind of *dowry* practice (Genesis 34:12) that I doubt the concubine's parents would get being that they were often slaves being a booty of war.  The bride would wear *special clothes* for the ceremony (eg., Jeremiah 2:32) and be accompanied by *bridesmaids* (Psalm 45:14).  Possibly a *wedding feast* was typical (Genesis 29:22).  There seems to have even been some kind of ritual leading to the act of sex where the woman is brought to the man for the purpose of *consummating* their intentions (Genesis 29:23). There was also some strange practice about proof of virginity based on the assumption that a virgin will bleed during her first time (Deuteronomy 22:13–21).

**With all the social customs surrounding the marriage concubinage seems to have been much more a matter of sexual gratification, slavery and increase in the number of children in a family**. Typically the concubines were of less status such as slaves (Genesis 16:2–3) and the wives would naturally rule over a slave/concubine in some sense.  As the ceremonies surrounding wives, especially the first wife, is not referred to for concubines, the less ceremonial 'cherishing of the event' must in some way have indicated an admission that the very nature of having additional sex partners was not the ideal represented by Adam and Eve.

Answer (score 2):

> In the Hebrew Bible, a marriage ceremony is never actually described.

True...hm...let me edit that...Song of Solomon might be one such description (if very poetic...but still might be or have a description of a wedding).

> Priests and their attendants (Kohanim and Levites) are responsible for
>   work in the sanctuary, such as sacrifices and offerings, so although
>   they're the people "consecrated to God" and act as intermediaries
>   between the people and God, they don't have any part in helping a man
>   and woman form a permanent union as "one flesh" and become husband and
>   wife.

Hadn't thought of that, but it's true.  Nothing in the law, that I remember.

> In Genesis, a union between man and woman is described as just a
>   commitment that two people make to live together, help each other, "be
>   fruitful and multiply."

But society around them was involved in the process...

> Isaac brought Rebecca "into his tent," and she became his wife, so in
>   their case, marriage is initiated between a couple when they engage in
>   sex.

That's not the only thing that happened.  Remember that Abraham sent his servant to look for a wife for Isaac (made him swear he would go and find a wife, but not take his son there).  Therefore, Abraham had to make something known to his servant, and this servant to the girl (while near a well, with lots of people around), and this girl and servant to her relatives, and THEN Rebecca accepted and WENT AAAAALL THE WAY to Abraham and Isaac's homestead to meet this groom.

So the thing wasn't: "Just have sex and become my wife."  There was a very important process before sex "happened."

Besides, Isaac's mother having died, and the society around Abraham and Isacc knowing this, it must have been "prutty" obvious that something "was up" with Isaac taking this girl (which Abraham sent his servant to look for!) into what used to be his mother's tent (Gen. 24:67)!

> Afterwards, they are understood as being bound to each other, and
>   thus living in a marriage. This is understandable, since biblical
>   times had a very different view of sex than what we see in modern
>   society.

Not too sure what you mean by "a different view of sex," but all of this makes a strong point for what is now called "traditional" wedding ceremonies: The acknowledgement of the couple by THEIR "society."

> Since a marriage ceremony is never described in the Bible, what
>   qualities would make a concubine different than a wife?

Status?  Recognition as such of the society around them?  At least recognizion as such of those who were in charge of writing the events (Scribes? Priests?).

> [...] is it just suggesting a social
>   status difference? A handmaid, even if she took up permanent residence
>   with one man, would never be a "wife", only a "concubine"?

"Bingo." Most likely.

> Bilhah and Zilphah are described as Jacob's "concubines", and Rachel
>   and Leah are described as "wives", although the children from all four
>   women are equal since they all become the twelve tribes. So why not
>   call Rachel and Leah's handmaids wives?

Because they were servants of the wives (which Jacob worked 14 years to have), which the wives themselves gave to Jacob, eager to "have" children when one couldn't and the other one could...lots o' competition between some women...

Comment: Regarding "14 years" before Jacob could have Rachel as his wife, I understood that a week after his marriage to Leah he was able to marry Rachel (but he had to promise to continue working for her father for another 7 years.

Answer (score 2):

A concubine was a wife, but of lesser social status. Concubines seem to have been wives acquired through slavery or else as payment of a debt; however, this made them no less legitimate than free-born wives. Keturah, for example, was referred to as a wife of Abraham in Genesis 25:1, but a concubine in vs. 6 of the same chapter (as well as later in 1 Chronicles 1:32). In summary, all concubines were wives, but not all wives were concubines.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  If you haven't done so already, check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour).  In particular, be sure to read the section on what constitutes a good answer and revise your post to either cite references that back your position or to more thoroughly explain how you get this interpretation from the text itself.  Please note that "showing your work" is [required](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/735/what-kind-of-site-do-we-ultimately-want-to-have/777#777) on this Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -2):

> This is why I ask about the difference between what a wife is and what a concubine is in biblical times. Since a marriage ceremony is never described in the Bible, what qualities would make a concubine different than a wife?

It's all about intent. If the mans intention in copulation with a woman was to make her his wife, then she was his wife afterwards. During copulation the two do become "one flesh", but they are only married if the intention was to marry. Remember after sex Judah was not married to Tamar and Samson was not married to the prostitute in Gaza. Intent. Intent. Intent.

The concubine was just a woman a man could "lay" with, but marriage was usually out of the question, probably because of social status.

Also as already stated, concubines were not given marriage contracts. Think of them as the "girlfriend's" of today.